# Python(pygame) class import scope troubles

Tags: python, import, module, scope, pygame

I am using Linux, with python3.5.

Having trouble trying to reduce the size of my main module, I have been trying to remove my class to a different module and I have been successful in some parts

ie: I can put the player class into the lib folder and hash out the player in the main, and it runs fine until I move the player into the cave or shop, the game at this stage crashes.

I understand this is a scope issue I have from a lot of reading up, I can see others have had similar problems but I just can't get my head around / understand the solution.

I have tried locating the problem using `print(globals())` in different locations to see if there is a difference. I assume this is due to the first call being from the guard and has the player defined inside this, but the player is not defined as a global like it was when I had the player class inside the main script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pygame
from Lib.Colours import *
import random
import os
#imports player class when its in different module
#from Lib.Player import *

# used for importing, when player class is in different module               
#from RPGv1_TryModule import *


class Player ( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):
    #player class blue print
    def __init__(self):
        
        super( Player, self ).__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Data/Images",'player1.png')).convert_alpha()
        self.image.get_rect()
        #gets players properites and stats
        self.set_properites()
        self.set_herostats()
        #set variable for H and V speed
        self.vertical_speed = 0
        self.horizontal_speed = 0
        #variables for area(map) and if in shop
        self.area = 0
        self.shop = 0
    
    def set_herostats(self):
        #players stats when first created
        self.lvl = 1
        self.hp = 100
        self.maxhp = 100
        self.att = [5, 10]
        self.defence = 1
        self.combatspeed = 1
        self.exp = 0
        self.maxexp = 100
        
    def set_properites(self):
        #gets size of player and sets center point
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.origin_x = self.rect.centerx
        self.origin_y = self.rect.centery
        #sets movement speed
        self.speed = 2
    
    def set_position( self, x, y ):
        #tracks players position
        self.rect.x = x - self.origin_x
        self.rect.y = y - self.origin_y
    
    def set_area(self, area ):
        #start positon set by area
        self.area = area
        self.set_position(area.player_start_x, area.player_start_y)

    def update(self, collide = pygame.sprite.Group, interact = pygame.sprite.Group, event=None):
        #player movement in x axis
        self.rect.x += self.horizontal_speed
        collision_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, collide, False )
        # collision detaction and making blocks in passable in x axis
        for collided_object in collision_list:
            if ( self.horizontal_speed > 0 ):  
                self.rect.right = collided_object.rect.left
                
            elif ( self.horizontal_speed < 0 ):
                self.rect.left = collided_object.rect.right
        #player movement in Y axis
        self.rect.y += self.vertical_speed
        collision_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, collide, False )
        # collision detaction and making blocks in passable in Y axis
        for collided_object in collision_list:
            if ( self.vertical_speed > 0 ):
                self.vertical_speed = 0   
                self.rect.bottom = collided_object.rect.top
                
            elif ( self.vertical_speed < 0 ):
                self.vertical_speed = 0
                self.rect.top = collided_object.rect.bottom
        #interactive block collision detection
        interaction_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, interact, False )
        # interactive block events
        for interaction in interaction_list:
            print(interaction.name)
            self.vertical_speed = 0
            self.horizontal_speed = 0
            if interaction.name == 'cave1':
                change_area(1)
            if interaction.name == 'Town':
                change_area()
            if interaction.name == 'shops':
                shopping()
        
        # key commands such as movement keys
        if not ( event == None ):
            if ( event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN ):
                
                if ( event.key == pygame.K_UP ):
                    self.vertical_speed += -self.speed
                
                if ( event.key == pygame.K_DOWN ):
                    self.vertical_speed += self.speed
                
                if ( event.key == pygame.K_LEFT ):
                    self.horizontal_speed += -self.speed
                
                if ( event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT ):
                    self.horizontal_speed += self.speed
                
                #key up sets speed back to 0 = player stop moving
            if ( event.type == pygame.KEYUP ):
                
                if ( event.key == pygame.K_UP ):
                    self.vertical_speed = 0
                
                if ( event.key == pygame.K_DOWN ):
                    self.vertical_speed = 0
                
                if ( event.key == pygame.K_LEFT ):
                    self.horizontal_speed = 0
                
                if ( event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT ):
                    self.horizontal_speed = 0
        # random battle logic (currently in construction)
        #if current_area.areatype == 'Cave':
            #0.1% chance to spawn mob while moving
         #   chance = random.randint(1,1000)
          #  if chance in range(1,2):
           #     if self.horizontal_speed != 0 or self.vertical_speed != 0:
            #        print('SpawnMob')


class Block( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):
    #none passable objects blueprint
    def __init__( self, x, y, width, height, colour = black ):
        
        super( Block, self ).__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface( ( width, height ) )
        
        self.image.fill ( colour )
        
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        
        self.rect.x = x 
        self.rect.y = y 

class Interactive_block( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):
    #interactive blocks blueprint( interactive event set in player class )
    def __init__( self, name, x, y, image ):
        super( Interactive_block, self ).__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Data/Images', image ) )
        self.name = name
        
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        
        self.rect.x = x 
        self.rect.y = y 
        
                
class Area ( object ):
    
    def __init__(self, player_object):
        #adding to sprite groups
        self.block_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.interactiveblock_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
        
        self.player_object = player_object
       
        self.player_start = self.player_start_x, self.player_start_y = \
                            0, 0
        #mob spawn variable
        self.areatype = None
        #world shift start variable
        self.world_shift_x = self.world_shift_y = 0
        #camera settings
        self.left_viewbox = display_width/2
        self.right_viewbox = display_width/2
        
        self.up_viewbox = display_height/2
        self.down_viewbox = display_height/2
        
    def shift_world(self, shift_x, shift_y ):
        #shifts blocks in area 
        self.world_shift_x += shift_x
        self.world_shift_y += shift_y
        
        for each_object in self.interactiveblock_list:
                each_object.rect.x += shift_x
                each_object.rect.y += shift_y
        
        for each_object1 in self.block_list:
                each_object1.rect.x += shift_x
                each_object1.rect.y += shift_y
        
    def run_viewbox(self):
        #basic camera to follow player
        if ( self.player_object.rect.x <= self.left_viewbox ):
            view_difference = self.left_viewbox - self.player_object.rect.x
            self.player_object.rect.x = self.left_viewbox
            self.shift_world ( view_difference, 0 )
            
        if ( self.player_object.rect.x >= self.right_viewbox ):
            view_difference = self.right_viewbox - self.player_object.rect.x
            self.player_object.rect.x = self.right_viewbox
            self.shift_world ( view_difference, 0 )
        
        if ( self.player_object.rect.y <= self.up_viewbox ):
            view_difference = self.up_viewbox - self.player_object.rect.y
            self.player_object.rect.y = self.up_viewbox
            self.shift_world ( 0, view_difference )
            
        if ( self.player_object.rect.y >= self.down_viewbox ):
            view_difference = self.down_viewbox - self.player_object.rect.y
            self.player_object.rect.y = self.down_viewbox
            self.shift_world ( 0, view_difference )

    def update(self):
        #update function for areas
        window.fill(self.backcolour)
        
        self.block_list.update()
        self.interactiveblock_list.update()
        
    def draw(self, window ):
        #draw function for areas
        self.block_list.draw( window )
        self.interactiveblock_list.draw( window )
    
class Main_town(Area):
    #start area 
    def __init__(self, Player_object ):
        
        super( Main_town, self ).__init__(Player_object)
        
        self.backcolour = green
        
        boarder_colour = water
        
        self.player_start = self.player_start_x, self.player_start_y = \
                            752, 711
        # used for no mob spawn
        self.areatype = 'Town'
        #none passable objects
        boarders = [
                [0, 2, 153, 997, boarder_colour ],
                [12, 851, 1841, 148, boarder_colour ],
                [1669, 0, 185, 988, boarder_colour ],
                [0, 0, 1834, 119, boarder_colour ],
                [194, 144, 1443, 33, wall ],
                [1600, 177, 37, 633, wall ],
                [196, 768, 1404, 42, wall ],
                [196, 171, 39, 597, wall ],
                [504, 408, 29, 362, wall ],
                [669, 173, 32, 166, wall ],
                [898, 167, 29, 169, wall ],
                [1047, 414, 35, 358, wall ],
                [1256, 172, 27, 194, wall ],
                [1421, 568, 185, 30, wall ],
                [1287, 611, 23, 157, wall ],
                [1442, 175, 17, 189, wall ],
              ]
        
        for block in boarders:
            block = Block( block[0], block[1], block[2], block[3], block[4] )
            self.block_list.add( block )
        
        #list of rough coords for objects, created with basic map editor 
        #shops coords  (371, 688)
        #shops coords  (323, 248)
        #shops coords  (548, 249)
        #shops coords  (809, 260)
        #caves coords  (1364, 241)
        #caves coords  (1529, 241)
        #caves coords  (1503, 692)
        #caves coords  (1200, 683)
        
        #interactive objects
        interactive_block = [
              ['cave1',1114,236,'Cave.png'],
              ['shops',240,175,'building.png'],
              ]
        
        for block in interactive_block:
            block = Interactive_block( block[0], block[1], block[2], block[3] )
            self.interactiveblock_list.add( block )


class Cave1(Area):
    # first cave map ( created with basic map editor )
    def __init__(self, Player_object ):
        
        super( Cave1, self ).__init__(Player_object)
        
        self.backcolour = grey

        boarder_colour = black
        
        self.player_start = self.player_start_x, self.player_start_y = \
                            193, 795
        # used for mob spawns
        self.areatype = 'Cave'
        # None passable objects
        boarders = [
            [0, 1, 159, 998, boarder_colour ],
            [148, 848, 1705, 151, boarder_colour ],
            [1725, 0, 128, 849, boarder_colour ],
            [61, 0, 1665, 81, boarder_colour ],
            [256, 641, 45, 214, boarder_colour ],
            [261, 77, 41, 197, boarder_colour ],
            [257, 366, 51, 115, boarder_colour ],
            [302, 421, 314, 33, boarder_colour ],
            [285, 643, 291, 33, boarder_colour ],
            [550, 672, 25, 58, boarder_colour ],
            [428, 198, 40, 226, boarder_colour ],
            [583, 75, 36, 346, boarder_colour ],
            [610, 418, 268, 39, boarder_colour ],
            [583, 442, 46, 129, boarder_colour ],
            [560, 714, 285, 17, boarder_colour ],
            [824, 567, 30, 151, boarder_colour ],
            [832, 701, 20, 68, boarder_colour ],
            [963, 291, 62, 566, boarder_colour ],
            [720, 222, 303, 70, boarder_colour ],
            [1011, 226, 274, 63, boarder_colour ],
            [1522, 78, 30, 148, boarder_colour ],
            [1551, 193, 53, 33, boarder_colour ],
            [1598, 194, 35, 495, boarder_colour ],
            [1350, 640, 247, 49, boarder_colour ],
            [1148, 448, 64, 311, boarder_colour ],
            [1388, 81, 36, 434, boarder_colour ],              
              ]
        
        for block in boarders:
            block = Block( block[0], block[1], block[2], block[3], block[4] )
            self.block_list.add( block )            
        # Interactive objects 
        interactive_block = [
              ['Town',1668, 98,'Cave.png'],
              ]
        
        for block in interactive_block:
            block = Interactive_block( block[0], block[1], block[2], block[3] )
            self.interactiveblock_list.add( block )

def change_area(area=0):
    # used to change area's possible improvement here
        global current_area
        area_list = []
        area_list.append( Main_town( Player.player ) )
        area_list.append( Cave1( Player.player ) )
        current_area_number = area
        current_area = area_list[ current_area_number ]
        Player.player.set_area( current_area )

# general text template
def text(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

# button template that uses mouse events
def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    #print(click)
    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(window, ac,(x,y,w,h))
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            action()
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(window, ic,(x,y,w,h))
    smallText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 18)
    textSurf, textRect = text(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
    window.blit(textSurf, textRect)

def shopping():
    # .shop used to break while loop
    Player.player.shop = 0
    shop = True
    while ( shop ):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ) or \
            ( event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and \
            ( event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE ) ):
                shop = False
                pygame.quit()
        if Player.player.shop == 1:
            break
       
        # shop interface                
        window.fill( white )
        largeText = pygame.font.SysFont('arial' ,55)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text("What would you like to do?", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/1.5))
        window.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
        
        #shop buttons
        button("Potion Store",display_width*0.16,display_height*0.85,display_width*0.13,display_height*0.09,green,bright_green,potionshop)
        button("Return to Town",display_width*0.68,display_height*0.85,display_width*0.13,display_height*0.09,red,bright_red,end_shop)
        
        clock.tick( 15 )
        
        pygame.display.update()
        
def potionshop():
    # .shop used to break while loop
    Player.player.shop = 0
    shop = True
    while ( shop ):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ) or \
            ( event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and \
            ( event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE ) ):
                shop = False
                pygame.quit()
        if Player.player.shop == 1:
            break

        # shop interface
        window.fill( grey )
        largeText = pygame.font.SysFont('arial' ,55)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text("Welcome to the potion store", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/1.5))
        window.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
        
        #shop buttons
        button("Small potion",display_width*0.14,display_height*0.75,display_width*0.13,display_height*0.09,green,bright_green,None)
        button("medium potion",display_width*0.28,display_height*0.75,display_width*0.13,display_height*0.09,green,bright_green,None)
        button("large potion",display_width*0.42,display_height*0.75,display_width*0.13,display_height*0.09,green,bright_green,None)
        button("massive potion",display_width*0.56,display_height*0.75,display_width*0.13,display_height*0.09,green,bright_green,None)
        button("Return to Store",display_width*0.70,display_height*0.75,display_width*0.13,display_height*0.09,blue,bright_blue,go_shopping)
        button("Return to Town",display_width*0.42,display_height*0.85,display_width*0.13,display_height*0.09,red,bright_red,end_shop)
        
        clock.tick( 15 )                  
        
        pygame.display.update()

def go_shopping():
    # .shop used to break while loop
    Player.player.shop = 1
    shopping()
    
def end_shop():
    # .shop used to break while loop
    Player.player.shop = 1
    change_area()
    
if ( __name__ == "__main__" ):
    pygame.init()
    
    boarder = 20
    display_size = display_width, display_height = 700, 350
    window = pygame.display.set_mode( display_size )
    
    pygame.display.set_caption ( "Battle RPG ")
    
    Player.player = Player()
    Player.player.set_herostats()
    active_object_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    active_object_list.add( Player.player )
    
    change_area()
    
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    frames_per_second = 60
      
    running = True
    while ( running ):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ) or \
            ( event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and \
            ( event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE ) ):
                running = False
            
                        
        # Update Functions
        Player.player.update(current_area.block_list,current_area.interactiveblock_list, event)
        event = None
        current_area.update()
        
        # Logic Testing
        current_area.run_viewbox()
        
        
        # Draw everything
        current_area.draw( window )
        
        active_object_list.draw( window )
        
        # Delay Framerate
        
        clock.tick( frames_per_second )
        
        
        # Update the screen                    
        
        pygame.display.update()
        
    pygame.quit()
```

Anyway here is the code (sorry it's long), I know it is probably a state I got some from a tutorial I followed the rest I stumbled through. You guys have helped me a lot without knowing almost every google search and there has been I hope for a StackOverflow result. Anyway, my main goal is:

1. Remove the player class from the main script and into its own module, while still being able to pass through areas; and then:
2. slowly remove the rest of the code (hopeful it will the same solution)
3. Get rid of the global I am using for current_area.

Thanks for reading and hopefully solving, I will continue hitting the wall until I crack this, and will post back any solution I find myself.

Answer (score 0):

Put Player in a file called player.py, put Block and InteractiveBlock in a file called blocks.py, put the Area stuff in area.py.  At the top of each one import pygame and any of the classes it uses, so if player is used in the Area class, you can either do `import player`, in which case you would have to write the_player = payer.Player() or `from player import Player`, in which case you can just write the_player = Player().

Put the rest in a file called main.py and import everything in there, player, area, and, block.

You refer to them the same as with other classes.

Current_area should surely be a Player class variable.

Comment: The Current_area to become a Player variable worked wonders , I over looked that.  I am still having troubles with the imports though after i move the player class and do the imports to main file and player.py file. I still get the crashes when i enter the cave or the shop (when i change location) I get a NameError: name 'player' is not defined.  I am not understanding where i need to define the player to allow it to be access through all functions and classes in my main script.  Thanks for you reply and help

Answer (score 0):

with help from marienbad from his post i have figured out what the issuse was.  As marienbad suggested to on how to import port classes i removed all the class into there own modules. leaving me with a cleaning work space to work with. I tried a few things and notice in my Area class i was passing the player object thus i tried to do the same with the change_area function and it work so modified code goes something like this for anyone else struggling witht his problem.

```
interaction_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, interact, False )
# interactive block events
for interaction in interaction_list:
    print(interaction.name)
    self.vertical_speed = 0
    self.horizontal_speed = 0
    if interaction.name == 'cave1':
        change_area(player, 1)
    if interaction.name == 'Town':
        change_area(player)
    if interaction.name == 'shops':
        shopping(player)
```

this is how I am now passing the player and into the functions

```
def shopping(player_object):
    # .shop used to break while loop
    player = player_object
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    player.shop = 0
    shop = True
    while ( shop ):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ) or \
            ( event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and \
            ( event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE ) ):
                shop = False
                pygame.quit()
        if player.shop == 1:
            break
```

And this is how the function receives the player class, thus keeping it defined.  Now this works as i have intended maybe a better solution but its the one that works and i understand. Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is here: `Player.player` - Player is a class, and has no player variable.  You just need to do `the_player = Player()` or `the_player = player.Player()` in your main to instantiate a player object, depending on how you are importing the Player class from the player module, as per above answer.  Try not to give variables the same name as modules. Also what is `Player_object`?

Comment: I have changed that in the code now player is now just player not player.player .  This was in the code as i thought it might of solved the problem.   Player_object is just a name for the variable i pass into the Area class . It can be changed to player , for easier understanding .  Also i did solve my problem the solution is below. thank you for your time and effort